# Any way to make this mesh (hair made from curves) manifold without having to manually retopo it?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, 3d-printing

So I'm working on this character figure that will be 3D printed, and I just finished the hair base, except it looks awful from below because of course it does :P
[image]
[image]

I was wondering if there was a way for me to "fix this" and make the mesh manifold at all? I tried using the head mesh to close off the hole but that is a pretty bad fix, as one would expect... I have a save file of the hair as curves, one of the hair as mesh but all separated, one of the hair as mesh all joined, and one where i boolean-joined all of the separate strands, but even then I can't figure out a way to make this work. I have access to zbrush as well, but I couldn't find a good way to do it in there either.

Comment: Have you tried remeshing it?

Comment: I did, but it ended up getting all.... hole-y only on the back. not sure if its a matter of choosing a higher resolution, but i dont know if my pc can handle it anyways ): ty tho!